# Written a Flexi React Component that is handed a JSON object.buting having logic error

Tags: reactjs

```js
const flexiConfig = {
  items: [
      {
        "name": "person_name",
        "label": "Person's Name",
        "type": 'TextField',
      },
      {
        "name": "states",
        "label": "Person's state",
        "type": "DropDown",
            "values": [
            "Maharashtra",
            "Kerala",
            "Tamil Nadu"
            ]
      }
    ]
};



class Flexi extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        
    }
  }
  
  onFlexSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(props.config.items)
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <form action="">
           <button type="submit">Submit</button>
         </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Flexi onSubmit={this.onFlexiSubmit} config={flexiConfig}/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.done {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

input {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Tried to do like this,

the component creates the appropriate TextField and DropDown HTML elements to allow the user to enter the necessary information. The component also renders a submit button that calls the onSubmit function supplied in the props with a JSON object as an argument that contains the user entered values for each of the items in flexiConfig.

what changes i need to make in order to get above one.

Comment: what are you trying to do? the question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but my understanding from your questions is that

- you're trying to render a form based on input from that json
- pass values back to the function which does something? (I just printed those)

relevant **flexi component**:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Flexi = ({ onSubmitFn, config }) => {
  const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState("");
  const [ddVal, setDdVal] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
  }, []);

  const changeHandler = e => {
    setInputVal(e.target.value);
  };

  const changeHandlerDD = e => {
    setDdVal(e.target.value);
  };

  const formSubmitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onSubmitFn({ name: inputVal, dd: ddVal });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Flex-ish form</h1>
      <form>
        {(config.length > 0) ?config.map((val, index) => {
          if (val.type === "TextField") {
            return (
              <div>
                <label htmlFor={val.label}>{val.label}:</label>
                <input type="text" id={val.label} onChange={changeHandler} />
              </div>
            );
          }
          if (val.type === "DropDown") {
            return (
              <div>
                <label htmlFor={val.label}>{val.label}:</label>
                <select type="text" id={val.label} onChange={changeHandlerDD}>
                  <option value="" />
                  {val.values.map(ddOption => {
                    return <option value={ddOption}>{ddOption}</option>;
                  })}
                </select>
              </div>
            );
          }
        }): <p>No data received</p> }
        <button type="submit" onClick={formSubmitHandler}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default Flexi;
```

relevant section in the **parent component**:

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "React",
      place: 'somewhere',      
    };
  }

  onFlexSubmit = (val) => {
    this.setState({ name: val.name, place: val.dd });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Flexi onSubmitFn={this.onFlexSubmit} config={flexiConfig.items} />
        <Hello name={this.state.name} place={this.state.place} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ddbxa6)